# Passing Gridrowindex to javascript error

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Im trying to pass a gridrowindex to a javascript function, but during runtime I keep getting an error saying `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`
Gridview is in a updatepanel should that make any difference

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quick Donate">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnQuickDonate" runat="server"
                                            CommandName="Insert"
                                            OnClientClick="chng(<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>,this);"

                                            onclick="btnQuickDonate_Click"
                                            Text="Quick Donate" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function chng(t, obj) {

                var CellValue, cell, tj;
                var table = document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID %>');
                cell = document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID %>').rows[parseInt(t) + 1].cells[1];
                tj = cell.innerHTML;
                alert(tj);

        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to do it

```
'<%# "chng(\"" + Container.DataItemIndex + "\")" %>'
```